# Rename getter and setter in Eclipse. Shortcut?

Tags: java, eclipse

Does anyone know a way to rename the getter and setter of a variable when I change the name of it?

The renaming function in eclipse is very useful, but, when I need to rename some variable, after that I need to manually fix the name of the getter and setter.

Comment: if they have no special logic delete them and generate them again

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Right click on the variable
2. Refactor -> Rename
3. A prompt should appear asking you for the new field name and whether the accessors be updated. Type the new field name and select the checkboxes for both the setter and getter. Then click `OK` and you're done.

[image]

If the prompt doesn't appear, open *Preferences->Java* and **unselect** the `Rename in editor without dialog` checkbox. Then redo the three steps.

[image]

Comment: i don't get the prompt

Comment: By default, no prompt appears, but it can be configured in the IDE>

Comment: You probably have the "Rename in editor without dialog" preference set (in Java preferences page).

Answer (score 11):

`ALT + Shift + R`.
Twice to show up 'Rename field' dialog and select 'rename getter/setter' option (this options will be remembered) so when you press `ALT + Shift + R` once, do inline rename and press Enter getter/setter are automatically renamed.